Back screen with Remote Desktop when setting up KUbuntu 24.04 on WSL 2.3.26.0 (Windows 11)
I'm trying to install KUbuntu 24.04 on WSL on my Windows 11 machine
The idea would be to connect to KUbuntu using the "usual" Remote Desktop client
My configuration is almost done; when I connect, I get the following login screen;

However, after entering my login and password, I get a black screen; then nothing happens
The procedure I follow is strongly inspired from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXAWNVgOUrw
https://www.vps-mart.com/blog/install-kde-plasma-and-xrdp-service-on-remote-ubuntu

I downloaded the standard Ubuntu 24.04 WSL image (I can't remember exactly where but possibly here), then, here is what I exactly do:

wsl --unregister MyWorkstation_24.04

wsl --import MyWorkstation_24.04 D:\WSL\Distro\MyWorkstation_24.04 D:\WSL\Downloads\ubuntu-noble-wsl-amd64-24.04lts.rootfs.tar.gz

wsl -d MyWorkstation_24.04
at this point, I am in a Linux shell (logged as root) in which I do

adduser myuser

usermod -aG sudo myuser

passwd myuser

nano /etc/wsl.conf
here I add at the end of the file the following content
 [user]
 default=myuser


exit



now I'm back to the dos/batch session and I run wsl --shutdown

wsl -d MyWorkstation_24.04
this time, I am in a Linux shell (logged as myuser). I can now run:

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo apt install neofetch htop net-tools -y

sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y

$ sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies kde-full -y
this step is quite long; at one point, I am asked to choose the display manager: I use to choose lightdm

sudo apt install xrdp -y

sudo cp /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini.bak

sudo sed -i 's/3389/3390/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

sudo systemctl restart xrdp

sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert

echo "/usr/bin/startplasma-x11" > ~/.xsession

nano ~/.xsessionrc
here write the following content
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=KDE
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/plasma:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-plasma:/etc/xdg:/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kf5-settings


sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start




Finally, I can get the IP of my WSL:
$ ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet\ " | xargs echo | cut -d" " -f2
172.23.65.151

Now, I can launch my remote desktop client to the obtained IP and port 3390

However, as explained at the beginning, I do not succeed to get a valid session: any help would be appreciated
Thank you

I found how to solve my problem; the main change is export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
I can now rewrite (and simplify) my installation procedure (this is a complete guide about how to install KDE/Plasma on Ubuntu 24.04)

wsl --unregister MyWorkstation_24.04

wsl --import MyWorkstation_24.04 D:\WSL\Distro\MyWorkstation_24.04 D:\WSL\Downloads\ubuntu-noble-wsl-amd64-24.04lts.rootfs.tar.gz

wsl -d MyWorkstation_24.04
at this point, I am in a Linux shell (logged as root) in which I do

adduser myuser

usermod -aG sudo myuser

nano /etc/wsl.conf
here I add at the end of the file the following content
 [user]
 default=myuser


exit



now I'm back to the dos/batch session and I run wsl --shutdown

wsl -d MyWorkstation_24.04
this time, I am in a Linux shell (logged as myuser). I can now run:

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo apt install net-tools -y

sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y

sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop kde-full -y

sudo apt install xrdp -y

sudo cp /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini.bak

sudo sed -i 's/3389/3390/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

nano ~/.xsession
here write the following content
 export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
 /usr/bin/startplasma-x11


sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart





Please click the check beside your answer to mark your answer as accepted.

Make sure to make it more readable next time :)
